# What is the time efficient way to calculate Global efficiency for large networks?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a network with 30000 nodes and over 40000 edges. I tried to calculate Global efficiency for my network with networkx but it's not time efficient. I was wondering what is the best library to calculate Global efficiency for large networks like mine?

Comment: FYI - I just noticed a typo in what I uploaded that would have lead to an incorrect result.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit 29 Sept - corrected a typo where I had an indent that shouldn't be there**

I looked at the networkx implementation and found an inefficiency (it considers each possible path independently, while there are ways to find many of the shortest paths all at once).  I've improved the method.

Try this code:

```
def my_global_efficiency(G):
    '''author Joel C Miller
       https://stackoverflow.com/a/57032282/2966723
    '''

    n = len(G)
    denom = n*(n-1)
    if denom>0:
        efficiency = 0
        for path_collection in nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G):
            source = path_collection[0]
            for target in path_collection[1]:
                if target != source:
                    efficiency += 1./path_collection[1][target]    
        return efficiency/denom
    else:
        return 0
```

Sample use:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(500,0.04)
nx.global_efficiency(G)
#answers will vary based on G
> 0.44650033400070577
my_global_efficiency(G)
> 0.44650033400070543
```

The difference in the last 3 digits is a rounding issue.  I think it is caused by some of the sums being done in a different order.

This will run significantly faster.  However, it may not be enough of an improvement for your purposes.

---

An alternate improvement if your graph is **undirected** would be to go to the networkx code, replace `denom` by half of its value and change the `permutations` to `combinations`.  Currently it looks at each pair of nodes and finds the distance in both directions.  If it's undirected, you only need to do this once.  So the change to `combinations` gives a factor of 2 improvement.

---

Depending on your graph it's not clear to me which change will be faster.  And these may still be too slow for your purposes.

You can speed up the process a bit more by getting an approximate value.  To do this, instead of using `nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length`, sample a large number of randomly chosen sources and find the distances of each of those specific nodes from all of the other nodes in `G` using `nx.single_source_shortest_path_length`.  So if you take `N=100` sources then there will be `denom=N*(n-1)` paths considered where `n` is the total number of nodes in `G`.  This should give over a factor of 300 speed up from the improved `my_global_efficiency`.